# Converting non-ASCII characters using slugify

Tags: django, filter, ascii

I am trying to slugify a couple of names including some non-ASCII characters :

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
```

Here is the kind of names I have to slugify : 中国：研究方法
As it is composed by non-ASCII characters, slugify returns an empty string.

Anything I can do to get around this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [unicode-slugify](https://github.com/mozilla/unicode-slugify):

```
pip install unicode-slugify
```

Then use it in code:

```
>>> import slugify
>>> print slugify.slugify(u'中国：研究方法')
中国研究方法
```